# JSoup error in data types

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I have the following code that is supposed to extract data from HTML document. I used eclipse. It gives me two errors (though, this code is copied and pasted from JSoup site as a tutorial). The errors in 1) File, and 2) Elements. I can't see any problem in these two types.

import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class TestClass 
{
 public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
{
     try{
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
  String linkHref = link.attr("href");
  String linkText = link.text();
}
     }//try
     catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
          }//catch

    }
}</i>
```

Comment: In the future questions, please don't ignore errors as if they are decoration only. Errors **are** at its own the whole answer to your problem. Your concrete problem is that you didn't understand them. You should then not be ignoring them, but copypasting them in your question, so that we can translate them in layman's terms for you, so that you can *understand* it (you know, once you understand a problem, the solution becomes totally obvious).

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `import` them.

```
import java.io.File;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
```

#### See also:

- [Java tutorial - Using package members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html)

---

Hint: **read** the "Quick Fix" options suggested by Eclipse. It's already the 1st option for `File`.

[image]